Ignite lock cache update
I have problem with ignite
so start with configuration
Server (cluster 4 node)
resources for 1 node

12 cpu (48 cluster)
32 gb ram

Ignite config (not default)

server mode (without client, only server)
activeJobs = 500
publicPoolSize = 500
waitJobs = 500
messageExpireTime = 3000
PersistenceEnabled = false
PeerClassLoadingEnabled = true
DefaultDataRegionConfiguration.InitialSize = 134217728
DefaultDataRegionConfiguration.allocatedMemory = 3221225472

Cache config

Atomic
Replicated

Application

spring boot 2.4.5
ignite 2.12
java 8
kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE

Application work this: Client (site or CRM) send request to balancer, then balancer send on one(random) node, then creating job, then job executing and response send to client (when problem is actual, time for response to client not increases)
So lets go to Problem
I have few caches (15), load cache from DB when i start my cluster and update data from Kafka.
11 caches updating by ignite.dataStreamer
4 with usual @KafkaListener, because i need listen 2 table, but this tables distribution data to 4 cache for more speed when i need get data from cache (i get data by key, not query). And @KafkaListener work on 1 node
and now i have BIG problem sometimes(!!!). For usual case i read and update cache 1.5k (MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG) record per 0.1 ms - 5sec, but sometimes its broken and cant read it fast. It read 1.5k, start read next 1.5k and do it so slowly...then kafka start rebalancing and repeat it again...This problem don't depend from count record in Kafka, because it can read 1 million record for 5 minutes and read 50k for 4 hour. But this problem can resolves itself without my participation, after few hours its start work normal
i am not sure where i need to pay attention. Because maybe it resources (low chance), or architecture, or versions, or configurations. Please help me find true way, because in test stand problem IS NOT REPEATED! (cry)
what i tried yet?

optimize code
change configurations
change RAM on server
up another cluster, full copy production cluster, and connect to prod Kafka for update data equal production, but without request from clients. Request from client it AVG 30 rps, 75 ms response. Problem is not repeated

next screens for understanding (i have flight record if you need)
in last screens with bad work, i stop KafkaListener on 4 nodes, and load cache from DB, and start KafkaListener again, and its start work fine

good work




bad work






before load cache
2024-11-12 12:46:56.202  UpdateOrCreate method finish 493219071 size 1500 time 2024-11-12T12:46:56.202
2024-11-12 12:46:56.203  UpdateOrCreate method 493219071 complete by 11
2024-11-12 12:46:56.203  ProcessStockDetailMessage finish StockDetailListener 493219071 time 2024-11-12T12:46:56.203
2024-11-12 12:46:56.203  ProcessStockDetailMessage StockDetailListener 493219071 complete by 11
2024-11-12 12:46:56.216  ProcessStockDetailMessage start StockDetailListener 777503849 time 2024-11-12T12:46:56.216
2024-11-12 12:46:56.721  UpdateOrCreate method start 777503849 size 1500 time 2024-11-12T12:46:56.721
2024-11-12 12:50:29.701 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | PriceServiceCommonConsumerFactory] AbstractCoordinator - Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2024-11-12 12:50:44.768 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | PriceServiceCommonConsumerFactory] AbstractCoordinator -  Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2024-11-12 12:52:43.033  UpdateOrCreate method finish 777503849 size 1500 time 2024-11-12T12:52:43.033
2024-11-12 12:52:43.033  UpdateOrCreate method 777503849 complete by 346
2024-11-12 12:52:43.033  ProcessStockDetailMessage finish StockDetailListener 777503849 time 2024-11-12T12:52:43.033
2024-11-12 12:52:43.034  ProcessStockDetailMessage StockDetailListener 777503849 complete by 346

after load cache
2024-11-12 14:08:41.222  ProcessStockDetailMessage start StockDetailListener 1575333558 time 2024-11-12T14:08:41.222
2024-11-12 14:08:41.363  UpdateOrCreate method start 1575333558 size 411 time 2024-11-12T14:08:41.363
2024-11-12 14:08:43.113  UpdateOrCreate method finish 1575333558 size 411 time 2024-11-12T14:08:43.113
2024-11-12 14:08:43.113  UpdateOrCreate method 1575333558 complete by 1
2024-11-12 14:08:43.113  ProcessStockDetailMessage finish StockDetailListener 1575333558 time 2024-11-12T14:08:43.113
2024-11-12 14:08:43.113  ProcessStockDetailMessage StockDetailListener 1575333558 complete by 1
2024-11-12 14:08:43.282  ProcessStockDetailMessage start StockDetailListener 433660022 time 2024-11-12T14:08:43.282
2024-11-12 14:08:43.776  UpdateOrCreate method start 433660022 size 1500 time 2024-11-12T14:08:43.776
2024-11-12 14:08:48.900  UpdateOrCreate method finish 433660022 size 1500 time 2024-11-12T14:08:48.900
2024-11-12 14:08:48.900  UpdateOrCreate method 433660022 complete by 5
2024-11-12 14:08:48.900  ProcessStockDetailMessage finish StockDetailListener 433660022 time 2024-11-12T14:08:48.900
2024-11-12 14:08:48.900  ProcessStockDetailMessage StockDetailListener 433660022 complete by 5


